# Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION create 3 foreign keys tha same table - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am creating a table through Entity Framework that contains 3 foreign keys to the same table `Account`:

```
public class EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        public EvaluationForm EvaluationForm { get; set; }
        public Guid FormId { get; set; }
        public Guid Evaluator_1_Id { get; set; }
        public Account Evaluator_1 { get; set; }
        public Guid Evaluator_2_Id { get; set; }
        public Account Evaluator_2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the migration and run the application I encounter this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_Evaluator1' on table 'EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

In the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` class, define as follows

```
public class EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluatorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator", ApplicationDataContext.DEFAULT_SCHEMA);

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

        entity.HasOne(d => d.EvaluationForm)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FormId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_EvaluatorForm");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Account)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AccountId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_Account");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Evaluator_1)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Evaluator_1_Id)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_Evaluator1");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Evaluator_2)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Evaluator_2_Id)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasConstraintName("FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_Evaluator2");
    }
}
```

Is this form the most correct way to create? and what would be the solution to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the warning is based on you having more than one reference to an Account, and if an Account were to be deleted, a cascade could get tripped up. Normally when you have a required relationship A=Requires=>B, if B is deleted then A would be deleted as well by default. (Required defaults to Cascade)  EF has flagged your model as having relationships that it likely cannot reliably cascade.

I believe to resolve the issue you should set the additional Account references DeleteAction to Restrict to satisfy EF. EF will throw an error if you attempt to remove a referenced Account without first cleaning up anything that references it.

```
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Evaluator_1)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Evaluator_1_Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) 
            .HasConstraintName("FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_Evaluator1");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Evaluator_2)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Evaluator_2_Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_EvaluationFormQuestionEvaluator_Evaluator2");
```

I believe the main Account reference should be Ok with the default cascade behaviour.

In any case, give it a try. This was a bit too much to put in a comment as it isn't something I could easily try and reproduce. If it doesn't work just leave a comment and I can delete the answer.  :)